# First Excel Macro "a query with the name already exists" error

Tags: excel, vba

so, I have created my first macro. When I close the workbook and open a copy, while running the macro, there is this error popping up:

"A query with the name "xxx" already exists"

That's the code:

```
Sub ImportPurchaseOrders()
'

' ImportPurchaseOrders Macro
' Uploads info regarding last week POs from NAV
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _
        "Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_18", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\krzysztof.latkowski\Desktop\Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF.LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_18.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=15, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Head" & _
        "ers"",{{""No."", Int64.Type}, {""Document Date"", type date}, {""Order Date"", type date}, {""Requested Receipt Date"", type date}, {""Posting Date"", type date}, {""Buy-from Vendor Name"", type text}, {""Buy-from Country/Region Code"", type text}, {""Amount"", type text}, {""Currency Code"", type text}, {""Status"", type text}, {""Purchaser Code"", type text}, {""C" & _
        "reated By"", type text}, {""Posting Description"", type text}, {""Ship-to Name"", type text}, {""BDC_Approved"", type logical}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_" _
        , "18"";Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM [Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_18]" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = _
        "Purchase_Orders_VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF_LATKOWSKI_2022_10_26T10_04_18"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF([@[Currency Code]]=""EUR"",[@Amount]*7.45,[@Amount])"
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Columns("I:I").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

I have tried adding some lines at the beginning, but it didn't help. That's my first macro and I am not sure what to do.

Would be happy to get some help on it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This will run into an error as the Query has already been created and the macro is trying to create again due to following code.

`ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _ "Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_18", Formula:= _ "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\krzysztof.latkowski\Desktop\Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF.LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_18.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=15, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Head" & _ "ers"",{{""No."", Int64.Type}, {""Document Date"", type date}, {""Order Date"", type date}, {""Requested Receipt Date"", type date}, {""Posting Date"", type date}, {""Buy-from Vendor Name"", type text}, {""Buy-from Country/Region Code"", type text}, {""Amount"", type text}, {""Currency Code"", type text}, {""Status"", type text}, {""Purchaser Code"", type text}, {""C" & _ "reated By"", type text}, {""Posting Description"", type text}, {""Ship-to Name"", type text}, {""BDC_Approved"", type logical}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""`

Add a test condition like below to avoid the error:

```
Dim blQryExists As Boolean
For Each qry In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
    If qry.Name <> "Purchase Orders VELTUFF_KRZYSZTOF LATKOWSKI 2022-10-26T10_04_18" Then
        blQryExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next qry
If blQryExists = False Then
    `Query condition here
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Where exactly should I add it?
It's highlighted in red in the query editor.

Comment: @cdealer Sorry, it was not formatted properly. Now I have re-formatted the test portion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like I didn't have to add anything to the code. It was enough just to delete this part:

Comment: @cdealer: That is up to you. You can either add the condition so that if in future if the query is deleted for some reason then it will get re-created due to `.add` or delete as you've already done.